# Python API Call authorization returns 401 for over the retrieval failure of JSESSIONID/Cookie/ClientID by request library

Tags: python, python-requests

I have simulated successfully API calls with my postman client.
Postman client automatically populates the required JSESSIONID, COOKIE, and CLIENT ID.

However, when I try to realize the same with python I get 401. It looks like the session variable of the request API does not hold the required information

I would like to replicate the entire step below with both Postman generated python script and my script

**Postman script**

In the first **POST** call, I use my secretKey to request the secret

```
import requests

url = "https://url.com/v1/session/auth/token?X-Requested-By=Maddy&Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

payload="secret_key=zxcvfc-103f-950d-856d-cxvfdgh&username=myuser001&access_level=FULL"
headers = {
  'X-Requested-By': 'Maddy', #This is my header
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', #My header
  'Cookie': 'route=e7esaafb42ce234234242347482341f; clientId= zxcvfc-103f-950d-856d-cxvfdg; JSESSIONID=e34cc53d-e99c-4296-a4fe-0d70a246bd11' #Postman generated
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

I get a secret **JHNXZasdasdasdasjdakdasdjdalsdjasdladasdlalsdjajsdjaskdjaksjdaskjdjaskdljasj** very long

then the second **GET** call is done with the secret I have received.

```
import requests

url = "https://url.com/callosum/v1/session/login/token?username=myuser001&auth_token=JHNXZasdasdasdasjdakdasdjdalsdjasdladasdlalsdjajsdjaskdjaksjdaskjdjaskdljasj&redirect_url=https://url.com/callosum/v1/tspublic/v1/user/list"

payload={}
headers = {
  'Cookie': 'route=e78as0dad9009q029420349249f; clientId=s0255-6598-5103-dec3-defererer090; JSESSIONID=dfgas8484-659595656-6526-5626-7589898ads'
}

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

#The response contains JSON output with a list of users

Not the above header junk that contains id and session and cookie is generated by the postman

**Now this is how my Python script looks like**

```
    url = "https://url.com/callosum/v1/session/auth/token?X-Requested-By=Maddy&Content-Type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    
    payload="secret_key=zxcvfc-103f-950d-856d-cxvfdgh&username=myuser001&access_level=FULL"
    headers = {
      'X-Requested-By': 'Maddy', #These one is mine
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' #these one is mine
    }
    with requests.session() as s:
       
        secret = s.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers,verify=False).text
        #secret contain the lengthy secret for the get call stored in the variable secret
        
        
        payload1 = {}

#The url2 contains login url and redirect url that contains the user API for get method 
        url2 = "https://url.com/callosum/v1/session/login/token?username=myuser001&auth_token={}&redirect_url=https://url.com/callosum/v1/tspublic/v1/user/list".format(secret)
        r = s.get(url2,data=payload1,verify =False)
        #Also tried without payload and with and without header results are the same
        print(r.cookies)
        print(r.text) #401 unauthroized
```

I get the secret but not the data. Do let me know if there is something that needs to be added.

Best Regards,
Gabby

Comment: Note I used trusted authentication with a secret key and then, i am requesting a secret token via post call with which I do a get request call over the login URL and access  the API over the redirect URL.

Comment: You should edit these details into your question. I strongly suggest add a GET of the URL you’re going to POST to, before adding your headers and payload for the POST. If it still doesn’t work, simplest method I’ve found is to trace a successful browser login using e.g. Telerik Fiddler, then update your Python code to replicate the headers/parameters/content/sequence of GET/POST.

Comment: Hello barny, the first call itself is a post and there is no Get, if this is what you mean. Authentication token requisition itself comes under post.

Comment: Yes - I’m saying you should add a GET before the POSt, exactly as your browser would do when you browse to the login page.